# Take array and convert to a hash Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, nokogiri

I am trying this for the first time and am not sure I have quite achieved what i want to. I am pulling in data via a screen scrape as arrays and want to put them into a hash.

I have a model with columns :home_team and :away_team and would like to post the data captured via the screen scrape to these

I was hoping someone could quickly run this in a rb file

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|team| team.text.strip}
away_team = doc.css(".team-away.teams").map {|team| team.text.strip}
team_clean = Hash[:home_team => home_team, :away_team => away_team]
puts team_clean.inspect
```

and advise if this is actually a hash as it seems to be an array as i cant see the hash name being outputted. i would of expected  something like this

```
{"team_clean"=>[{:home_team => "Man Utd", "Chelsea", "Liverpool"}, 
          {:away_team => "Swansea", "Cardiff"}]}
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution

```
team_clean = Hash[:team_clean => [Hash[:home_team => home_team,:away_team => away_team]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually get a Hash back. But it looks different from the one you expected. You expect a Hash inside a Hash.

Some examples to clarify:

```
hash = {}
hash.class
 => Hash 

hash = { home_team: [], away_team: [] }
hash.class
=> Hash
hash[:home_team].class
=> Array

hash = { hash: { home_team: [], away_team: [] } }  
hash.class
=> Hash
hash[:hash].class
=> Hash
hash[:hash][:home_team].class
=> Array
```

The "Hash name" as you call it, is never "outputed". A Hash is basically a Array with a different index. To clarify this a bit:

```
hash = { 0 => "A", 1 => "B" }
array = ["A", "B"]
hash[0]
=> "A"
array[0]
=> "A"
hash[1]
=> "B"
array[1]
=> "B"
```

Basically with a Hash you additionally define, how and where to find the values by defining the key explicitly, while an array always stores it with a numerical index.